# Dynamic ng-blur for the dynamic field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I dynamically add ng-blur events to the input fields I am getting an error

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$parse/syntax?p0=field.validate&p1=is%20u…ing%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bfield.validate%7D%7D&p4=field.validate%7D%7D

Please help.

FYI - When I hard code `ng-blur="Test1()"` it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/subhajayabalan/6tfnzy82/2/

or

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form name="myForm">

        <p ng-repeat="field in formFields">
                <input
                    dynamic-name="field.name"
                    type="{{ field.type }}"
                    placeholder="{{ field.name }}"
                    ng-model="field.value"
                    ng-blur="{{ field.validate }}"
                    required
                >
        </p>

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.firstName.$valid = {{ myForm.firstName.$valid }}
        </code>    

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.email.$valid = {{ myForm.email.$valid }}
        </code>            

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.$valid = {{ myForm.$valid }}
        </code>

        <hr>               

    </form>

</div>
```

### Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.formFields = [
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            type: 'text',
            validate:'Test1()'
        },
        {
            name: 'email',
            type: 'email',
            validate:'Test2()'
        }
    ];

    $scope.Test1 = function()
    {
        console.log("Text1 On Blur Event works");
    }

     $scope.Test2 = function()
    {
        console.log("Text2 On Blur Event works");
    }   
}

myApp.directive("dynamicName",function($compile){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        terminal:true,
        priority:1000,
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.attr('name', scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicName));
            element.removeAttr("dynamic-name");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ng-blur** is expecting a function (IE doStuff()) not a pointer which is what you are getting with the expression {{..}}. That's why it correctly compile/parse and won't fire the blur action.

You can do a workaround by creating a common function and iterate/do stuff by examining the index:

```
 ng-blur="doStuff($index)"
  ...
 $scope.doStuff = function(idx){
    console.log("Text"+idx+" On Blur Event works");
 }
```

[Complete jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb1d6vd2/2/)

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form name="myForm">

        <p ng-repeat="field in formFields">
                <input
                    dynamic-name="field.name"
                    type="{{ field.type }}"
                    placeholder="{{ field.name }}"
                    ng-model="field.value"
                    ng-blur="doStuff($index)"                
                    required
                >
        </p>

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.firstName.$valid = {{ myForm.firstName.$valid }}
        </code>    

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.email.$valid = {{ myForm.email.$valid }}
        </code>            

        <code class="ie">
            myForm.$valid = {{ myForm.$valid }}
        </code>

        <hr>               

    </form>

</div>
```

Angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.formFields = [{
        name: 'firstName',
        type: 'text'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        type: 'email'
    }];

    $scope.doStuff = function(idx){
    console.log("Text"+idx+" On Blur Event works");
};
}

myApp.directive("dynamicName", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('name', scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicName));
            element.removeAttr("dynamic-name");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```